# Why the text of the TextField won't updated after state change?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I just started learning compose, and I don't really understand the re-composition, like when and how it happens.

So I have a drop down menu, when I change the item, it will trigger a callback, so the UserManagerScreen updates the state by viewModel.updateEvent(UserManagerEvent.OnRoleChanged(user, newRole)) method.

The state object contains the list which will be updated every time, when I change the role type. The update is done by the viewModel like this:

```
     _state.value.userList.find { it.id == user.id }?.apply {
            role = newRole
        }

        _state.update { userManagerState ->
            userManagerState.copy(
                userList = _state.value.userList
            )
        }
```

Theoretically when the state is updated, re-composition happens, so the UserRoleDropdownMenu() will be called again, with the updated text. Maybe I understand it wrong, but the drop down menu item TextField doesn't get the updated text.

In the example, what I followed, the UserRoleDropdownMenu should have for example a state which contains the selected Role, and also have to update it in the onClick() event. If I do this, the text will be updated, but it seems a little bit unnecessary for me.

```
@Composable
fun UserManagerScreen(
    modifier: Modifier,
    viewModel: UserManagerViewModel = hiltViewModel<UserManagerViewModel>()
) {
    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        items(state.userList, key = {
            it.id
        }) { user ->
            UserWithRoleItem(userWithRoleView = user) { newRole ->
                viewModel.updateEvent(UserManagerEvent.OnRoleChanged(user, newRole))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UserWithRoleItem:

```
@Composable
fun UserWithRoleItem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    userWithRoleView: UserWithRoleView,
    onSelectionChanged: (newRole: RoleEnum) -> Unit
) {
    Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp),
                text = userWithRoleView.userName
            )

            UserRoleDropdownMenu(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                selectedUserRole = userWithRoleView.role){
                onSelectionChanged(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the UserRoleDropDown:

````
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun UserRoleDropdownMenu(
   modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
   selectedUserRole: RoleEnum,
   onSelectionChanged: (newRole: RoleEnum) -> Unit
) {
   val roles = RoleEnum.entries.toTypedArray()
   var expanded by remember {
       mutableStateOf(false)
   }

   Box(modifier = modifier) {
       ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
           expanded = expanded,
           onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded }
       ) {
           TextField(
               value = selectedUserRole.name,
               onValueChange = {},
               readOnly = true,
               trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
               modifier = Modifier
                   .menuAnchor()
                   .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
           )

           ExposedDropdownMenu(
               expanded = expanded,
               onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
           ) {
               roles.forEach { role ->
                   DropdownMenuItem(
                       text = {
                           Text(text = role.name)
                       },
                       onClick = {
                           onSelectionChanged.invoke(role)
                           expanded = false
                       })
               }
           }
       }
   }
} ```
````